# Remote not firing in ASP Core 1.0 RC2

Tags: validation, asp.net-core

The Remote attribute is not firing to the controller on validation. Does anyone have a clue why not?

I have the following class:

```
public class XUser{
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "This is an incorrect ID")] //Just a test
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckUsername", "Home")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage ="This is not an email adres!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The following Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(Int64 id) {
    return View(users.Where(u => u.ID == id).SingleOrDefault());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(XUser user) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } else {
        return View(user);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult CheckUsername(string Name) {
    return Json(false);
}
```

And last but not least, the following view:

```
@model XUser
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.ID) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Email) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Email)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

In my _Layout I have the following scripts included:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

I also tried the following:

```
//Class
[Required]
[Remote("CheckUsername", "Home", HttpMethod = "POST")]
public string Name { get; set; }
//Controller
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult CheckUsername(string Name) {
    return Json(false);
}
```

Comment: What is ASP Core 2.0 ... ?

Comment: @Tseng that should've been 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question for further reference, if anyone else will come along the same problem. I could've seen it in the solution explorer, but some things you just overlook and can save a lot of time!

With Fiddler I saw that the JQuery files were not found. The paths did not match anymore with MVC 4.0 / 5.0 paths.
They have been moved from:

```
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

To:

```
~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js
~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

Further; AllowAnonymous is not obligated to have as an attribute with Remote[] (For neither HttpPost or HttpGet).